# is it possible to skip logging stacktrace by SeekToCurrentErrorHandler?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I just configured SeekToCurrentErrorHandler in spring cloud stream with kafka project and I see tons of logs (one stacktrace per each delivery attempt) which I would like to silence. Is it possible?

PS. I do not know if it is relevant (and whether I do it right. Comments are welcome ;)), but I am throwing an exception from my @StreamListener which is handled by @ServiceActivator and inside it I am rethrowing wrapped exception in order to run error handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with spring-kafka version 2.5 (comes with Boot 2.3) you can set the log level.

```java
/**
 * Set the level at which the exception thrown by this handler is logged.
 * @param logLevel the level (default ERROR).
 */
public void setLogLevel(KafkaException.Level logLevel) {
    Assert.notNull(logLevel, "'logLevel' cannot be null");
    this.logLevel = logLevel;
}
```

Comment: Luckily we are able to bump up the version. Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PiotrTempes I'm facing the same issue. Can you please share which version resolved the issue. I'm using spring kafka 2.6.11 and I was not able to suppress logging the stacktrace by changing the log level.

Comment: Please ask a new question showing the code, config, and stack trace.

Comment: @venky unfortunately I am no longer working on this project, I do not have access to it's codebase and it was quite some time ago so I do not remember from top of my head. I think you should do as Gary suggested above. Ask new question providing as much info as possible. The version you are using should be ok so I guess it is a configuration issue. Kafka comes with a lot of different abstractions in spring, so maybe in your case a different configuration kicks in? Hard to tell based on information you posted. Just dig a little bit deeper. I am sure you will get to it eventually. Good luck!